# User Account Control keeps turning on by itself after I turn it off

Tags: windows-10, uac

User Account Control keeps turning on by itself after I turn it off. How do I stop this?

I don't have the Pro edition of windows so I don't have group policy editor. My windows user is an administrator, and it's not part of a network so my user settings are not controlled by a network administrator.

[image: user account control settings]

Comment: How exactly are you turning off UAC.  UAC in Windows 8+ can only be disabled with a group policy.  Since you have Windows 10 Home I have a suspicion whatever method you have been using isn’t actually disabling UAC.  You can [edit] your question so there is an appropriate amount of information so that your question can be answered.  Turning UAC to never notify doesn’t actually disable UAC.  **Disabling UAC on Windows 10 will disable all UWP applications.**

Comment: I have updated my question with the method I used.

Comment: See the duplicate.  That doesn’t disable UAC on Windows 10

Comment: It is utterly foolish and ridiculous to turn UAC OFF. Up to you, but wise people leave it on.

Comment: @John - I agree; However, it being dangerous, doesn’t answer the question.

Comment: Turning UAC off isn't dangerous and isn't real security. It's more of a "are you sure you want to do this?" to prevent newbies who aren't computer savvy from making bad decisions. All UAC does is alert me if I truly want to do the things I chose to do. Like if I want to open a website in Firefox, if I want to rename a file, or if I want to install a program. But of course I want to do it, otherwise I wouldn't have chosen to do it. If I opened a virus, UAC won't detect the file as a virus, or even block the virus from running. It would just ask me if I wan to run it. It cannot detect threats.